# appropriate functions to override when executing subquery on encrypted binary data

Tags: ios, core-data, subquery, codec

I'm considering encrypting every attribute in a sqlite data model.  Encrypting the data clearly complicates accessing attribute values, saving attribute values, and searching for attribute values from the perspective of the view (in MVC).

I was thinking it may suffice to override NSFetchedResultsController methods `fetchedResults` and `performFetch:`, and NSManagedObjectContext method `save:`

I have also gotten into loads of trouble by assuming it was okay to override in the past.

Since this will likely take some time to work through all the details, I would like to know if anyone has discovered (and verified) an appropriate way to add codec mechanisms such that it's not necessary to encode and decode at every place in code where I search, access and save persistent data?  And if so, what was the approach?

Comment: I wouldn't think overriding `NSFetchedResultsController` would do any good since it mostly just organizes results produced by an `NSManagedObjectContext` executing an `NSFetchRequest`. Regardless, I'm no expert in this field, but I'm curious to know what the advantage of per-attribute encryption is over encrypting the SQLite store? If you have a moment to explain I'd appreciate it. Thank you and good luck!

Comment: I've already implemented a data model.  I'm looking for the easiest way to ensure the sensitive data is encrypted no matter what.  Using Apple provided encryption when the passcode is enabled has known vulnerabilities, and doesn't guarantee the data will be encrypted.  Otherwise, I'm not aware of a way to encrypt the file with the code I currently have in place.  As I understand it, the core data framework has to create the sqlite file, or you have to bypass core data entirely.

Comment: Oh, right, understood. I'll have to look into those vulnerabilities. I appreciate the explanation!